# A complex IS-A relation ER diagram

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am trying to create a relational schema [using this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2SGz.jpg).

But i don't know where to start. Can someone suggest some references to help get me started?

Answer (score 1):

Start by specifying the types of facts that you want to record, in the form of predicate sentences with placeholders for values.  For example:

- The country with code `<COUNTRY_CODE>` is named `<COUNTRY_NAME>`
- The language with code `<LANGUAGE_CODE>` is an official language of `<COUNTRY_CODE>`
- `<COUNTRY_CODE>` has a `<SUBDIVISION_TYPE>` called `<SUBDIVISION_NAME>`
- `<COUNTRY_CODE>` has a city called `<CITY_NAME>` in `<SUBDIVISION_NAME>`

Next, identify the domains of each placeholder as well as subset relationships between domains (these are your IS-A relationships and will eventually be enforced via foreign key constraints).  Identify functional and multivalued dependencies, and normalize where required.  If you kept your fact types simple you won't need much of the latter.

For more information, look into fact-based (i.e. relational) modeling disciplines like Object-Role Modeling.